# React work from Redux . TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, undefined

I encountered such a problem, I did it according to the template, but something went wrong. The project with files can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/DaniLLutsiv/Wooder.git)

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
DataReducer
D:/React_learn/Gitwooder/Wooder/wooder/src/Redux/DataReducer.js:20
  17 | 
  18 | const DataReducer = (state = initialState , action) => {
  19 | 
> 20 |  switch(action.type){
  21 |      case 'HIDE-MENU' :
  22 |      console.log('doschlo')
  23 |      return{
```

Comment: You need to check the area where you've triggered the action, you've missed adding the required object with type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says you don't have a type property in your action.

You should dispatch an action like this: `dispatch({type: 'HIDE-MENU'})`

If it's still doesn't work then I would like you to share your stack trace so we'll be able to see from where the action was dispatched

EDIT:

Your mapDispatchToProps is incorrect. Each property in the mapDispatchToProps should be a function that uses the dispatch passed by react-redux. Remember that the result of the mapping will be eventually attached to the props in the component. I suggest you re-read the documentation: https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect

This is the correct way:

```js
import React from 'react';
import classes from './Header.module.css';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

//***** CHANGE 1 *****
import { HidemenuAC } from '../../Redux/DataReducer';


const Header = (props) =>{

    const Menu_view = () =>{
        props.Hidemenu(true)
    }

    return <header className={classes.Header}>
        <div className={classes.Header_menu} onClick={Menu_view}>
            <div>
                <div className={classes.line}></div>
                <div className={classes.line}></div>
                <div className={classes.line}></div>
            </div>
            <div className={classes.Header_menu_text} tabIndex="0">MENU</div>
        </div>
        <div className={classes.Big_line}></div>
        <ul className={classes.HeaderUl}>
            <li>HOME</li>
            <li>PRODUCTS</li>
            <li>ABOUT</li>
        </ul>
        <div className={classes.Header_circle} >i</div>
        <div className={classes.Header_arrow}>EN &#9660;</div>
    </header>
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return{
       Menu:state.Data.Menu
    }    
}

//***** Change 2 ******
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    Hidemenu: (value) => dispatch(HidemenuAC(value))
})

//***** Change 3 ******
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Header);
```

Comment: I send type through AC.export const HidemenuAC = (bool) => {
 return {
  type:'HIDE-MENU',
  bool: bool
 }
}

Comment: Из какого файла братан?

Comment: call AC from DataReducer.js

Comment: вызов колбека из Header.js

Comment: Понял, Я изменил свой ответ, попробуй сейчас

Comment: Я вставил твой кусок , не работает. Также я сам писал такой же код , он тоже был с ошибкой.

Comment: Я думаю, что я нашел, попробуй сейчас. измени import(Я добавил {}):
import { HidemenuAC } from '../../Redux/DataReducer';

Comment: Сработало , спасибо тебе огромное )

Comment: Не за что) Прочетай про "export vs export default" https://medium.com/@krishankantsinghal/named-exports-vs-default-exports-c0dffa21946d